# Pass custom ArrayList with Serializable interface to the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I am sending a request to the server from the `MainActivity` then I am getting a response in the `GETLLRD` class.

I want to pass  `ArrayList<ItemDTO>` to the `Map` activity which I have already registered in the manifest.xml but I am getting the error below. How can I pass an custom arrayList to the `Map` activity and start it from the `onPostExecute` method in the AsyncTask class? I am tried it with the use of the `Serializable` in the `ItemDTO` class.

I appreciate any help.

**Error:**

```
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 24568
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at com.bustracker.GetLLRD$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetLLRD.java:62)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at com.bustracker.GetLLRD$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(GetLLRD.java:1)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-06 17:06:18.039: E/AndroidRuntime(24568):    ... 4 more
```

**GetLLRD class**

```
public class GetLLRD {
    Context mContext;

    public void post_selected(String json, Context context) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(json);
        context = this.mContext;
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<ItemDTO>> {


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<ItemDTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

          .
          .
          .
          .

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                }.getType();
                ArrayList<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType);
                                for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {
                double latitude = itemDTO.getLatitude();
                double longitude = itemDTO.getLongitude();
                int route = itemDTO.getRoute();
                String direction = itemDTO.getDirection();
                System.out.println(latitude + ", " + longitude + ", "
                        + ", " + route + ", " + direction);

            }
          .
          .
          .
          .     


            return data;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemDTO> result) {

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
                    System.out.println("The method onPostExcute() in GETLLRD class was invoked  again");
                }
            }, 1*30 * 1000);

            if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Map.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",result);
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 

            }else{
                Log.e("123", "Avoiding null pointer, the dat is null in the GETLLRD class!!!");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**MapDataJSON  class with the inner class ItemDTo which I need to get the data from the JSON string that I am getting from the Server.**

```
public class MapDataJSON {
    ArrayList<ItemDTO> items;

    public MapDataJSON(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        super();
        this.items = items;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemDTO> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemDTO> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public static class ItemDTO  implements Serializable  {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        int route;
        String direction;

        public ItemDTO(double latitude, double longitude, int route,
                String direction) {
            super();
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.route = route;
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        public double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public int getRoute() {
            return route;
        }

        public String getDirection() {
            return direction;
        }

        public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public void setRoute(int route) {
            this.route = route;
        }

        public void setDirection(String direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ItemDTO>>() {
                }.getType();
                ArrayList<ItemDTO> data = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), listType); what happen if you run this code outside async task? and what is under variable sb - are you sure it's proper json? hm wrap this code in try catch block and log error it should help

Comment: use intent.putStringArrayListExtra("list", list); in your activity,you can get the list by getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("list")

Comment: @rainash: I am getting `The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<MapDataJSON.ItemDTO>)`?

Comment: @  Marcin Mierzejewski: I have debuged it and I can see the `latitde, longiuted, route and direction ` inside the data object. I have wrap  the code in `try catch (JsonSyntaxException e) ` blok but the error is still appearing.

Comment: @TheBook: Why don't You try to wrap it with more generic "Exception" or "Throwable"? Maybe try change second param like: new TypeReference<List<SomeClass>>(){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the list is empty.Please check whether you getting correct data from server:

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0**

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html), the error is thrown when :

> public class ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException extends
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException
>
> Thrown to indicate that an array has been
>   accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or
>   greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Comment: I have already checked it and I can see the data `latitude, longitude, route and direction `. I have even output them in the doInBackground method. Why is the list then empty?

Comment: Probably the data is not parsed properly..the format is not correct...Can you put the exact line number where it is throwing the error.

Comment: I am outputing it after the parsing `for (ItemDTO itemDTO : data) {}` and I have wraped the lines above in catch block also there is no `JsonSyntaxException e` error?!

Comment: I dont know which line is that can I see it in the error?

Comment: It is showing line no 62 in GetLLRD.java... doInBackground(GetLLRD.java:62)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you could debug it.

To send serializable data:

```
intent.putExtra("datalist",(Serializable)yourList);
```

To get data:

```
list = (ArrayList<POJOModel>)intent.getSerializableExtra("datalist");
```